# Is this a snowdrop?

Tags: identification

[image]I found plants growing in shade under trees. The flower hangs down like a snowdrop but is much smaller, delicate, and is all white. The leaves are wider than the usual snowdrop, more like a bluebell leaf. What is it please? I live in the north of the UK.

Answer (score 1):

Leucojum aestivum?  the strappy leaves give it away- not rare just uncommon- nice plant though- hope it helps.

Comment: It could be, although the plant in question has an all white, single  flower on the stalk with no green touches at all. The bulbs are small and white.